# Disable numbers of calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a small calculator project, so far I think it's decent but I have an issue that I don't know how to fix.

1. When you select a number (+ or - or / or *) number and press equal it throws the result (ie 3 * 3 = 9) but if you keep pressing numbers then it will add those numbers to the result (ie result 912345), if you press any of the operands then it will work normally but I can't fix that small detail, I would like to disable all the numbers after the first result until you press any of the operands to keep operating like a real calculator.

I don't know if the calculator is set properly, so far I have not encountered any other bugs.

```js
let currentNum = '';
let prevNum = '';
let operator = '';

let prevNumDisplay = document.querySelector('.prev-result');
let currentNumDisplay = document.querySelector('.current-result');
let clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear');
let equalBtn = document.querySelector('.equal');
let decimalBtn = document.querySelector('.decimal');
let numbersBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
let operatorsBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');

numbersBtn.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        getNumber(event.target.textContent);
    })
})

operatorsBtn.forEach((op) => {
    op.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        getOperator(event.target.textContent);
    })
})

equalBtn.addEventListener('click', calculate);

clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clearCalc);

decimalBtn.addEventListener('click', addDecimal);

function addDecimal() {
    if (!currentNum.includes('.')) {
        currentNum += ".";
        currentNumDisplay.textContent = currentNum;
    }
}

function clearCalc() {
    prevNum = '';
    currentNum = '';
    prevNumDisplay.textContent = ''
    currentNumDisplay.textContent = '0';
}

function calculate() {
    prevNum = Number(prevNum);
    currentNum = Number(currentNum);

    if (operator === '+') {
        currentNum = prevNum + currentNum;
    } else if (operator === '-') {
        currentNum = prevNum - currentNum;
    } else if (operator === 'x') {
        currentNum = prevNum * currentNum;
    } else if (operator === '÷') {
        currentNum = prevNum / currentNum;
        if (currentNum >= Infinity || currentNum <= -Infinity) {
            currentNumDisplay.textContent = 'ERROR';
            prevNumDisplay.textContent = '';
            prevNum = '';
            currentNum = '';
            return;
        }
    }
    displayResults();
}

function displayResults () {
    currentNum = currentNum.toString();
    if (currentNum.length <= 10) {
        currentNumDisplay.textContent = currentNum;
    } else {
        currentNumDisplay.textContent = currentNum.slice(0, 10) + "..";
    }

    if (prevNum.length < 10) {
        prevNumDisplay.textContent = currentNum;
    } else {
        prevNumDisplay.textContent = currentNum.slice(0, 10) + "..";
    }
    
    prevNumDisplay.textContent = '';
    operator = '';

}

function getOperator(opt) {
    operator = opt;
    prevNum = currentNum;

    prevNumDisplay.textContent = `${prevNum} ${operator}`;
    currentNumDisplay.textContent = '';
    currentNum = '';
}

function getNumber(number) { 
    
    if (currentNum.length <= 11) {
    currentNum += number;

    currentNumDisplay.textContent = currentNum;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.calcContainer {
    background: linear-gradient(276deg, #d6bbe0, #72c3dd);
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0.1em;
    width: 40px;
}

.clear {
    margin: 0em 0em 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.output-clear-container {
    display: flex;
}

.output {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.prev-result {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    color:white
}

.current-result {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calcContainer">
        <div class="output-clear-container">
            <div class="output">
                <div class="prev-result">0</div>
                <div class="current-result">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="body-clear"><button class="clear">AC</button></div>
        </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">7</button>
                <button class="number">8</button>
                <button class="number">9</button>
                <button class="operator">÷</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">4</button>
                <button class="number">5</button>
                <button class="number">6</button>
                <button class="operator">x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">1</button>
                <button class="number">2</button>
                <button class="number">3</button>
                <button class="operator">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="decimal">.</button>
                <button class="number">0</button>
                <button class="equal">=</button>
                <button class="operator">+</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: "_I would like to disable all the numbers after the first result until you press any of the operands to keep operating like a real calculator_": While this is your calculator and you can determine any behavior you'd like, I'd like to point out that almost every calculator I've used doesn't work this way: instead, they allow for starting new operations with new operands immediately after viewing a result (ignoring the result if a value key is pressed first).

Comment: Agree with @jsejcksn. I'd much rather assist in a fix that inserts an implicit AC on the next numeric keypress after =.

Comment: Also note that 6x6x6 doesn't work as a standard calculator does.  I'd characterize this as a "state machine" problem for this project.

Comment: @jsejcksn So basically mi calculator is not a calculator, and yeah, I have tried 6x6x6 and it doesn't work... I will start the project again once I have read some more documentation, thank you both.

Comment: @danh message above is also for you, couldn't mention you, thanks.